# Asp.NET CSHTML data read from an ICollection list in a for loop are not getting set at page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, icollection, devexpress-mvc

I have a model (RecruitingForm) with some fields (ex: DepartmentId) and a ICollection sub-list (RecruitingFormsRows). I am initializing the object like so and I send it to the view.

```
RecruitingForm model = new RecruitingForm();
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    RecruitingFormsRow modelRow = new RecruitingFormsRow();
    model.RecruitingFormsRows.Add(modelRow);
}

LoadViewData(); //Loads the date for the combo boxes in ViewData
return View("AddRecruitingForm", model);
```

The variables that are in the main object are set correctly at load or (if error) at response, but the once that are inside the ICollection (RecruitingFormsRows) are not in both cases. My view looks like this:

```
@model RecruitingForms.Database_models.RecruitingForm

using (Html.BeginForm("AddRecruitingForm", "RecruitingForms"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.DevExpress().FormLayout(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "AddRecruitingForm";
    settings.Width = Unit.Pixel(1024);

    var groupItem = settings.Items.AddGroupItem(groupSettings =>
    {
        groupSettings.CellStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        groupSettings.Caption = @Resources.Resource.RecruitingForm;

        groupSettings.ShowCaption = DefaultBoolean.True;
        groupSettings.GroupBoxDecoration = GroupBoxDecoration.Default;
    });

    groupItem.SettingsItems.ShowCaption = DefaultBoolean.True;
    groupItem.SettingsItemCaptions.Location = LayoutItemCaptionLocation.Top;
    groupItem.SettingsItemHelpTexts.Position = HelpTextPosition.Top;


    var groupItemLayer2 = groupItem.Items.AddGroupItem(groupSettings =>
    {
        groupSettings.CellStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        groupSettings.ShowCaption = DefaultBoolean.True;
        groupSettings.Caption = "";
        groupSettings.GroupBoxDecoration = GroupBoxDecoration.Default;
        groupSettings.ColumnCount = 3;
        groupSettings.SettingsItems.HorizontalAlign = FormLayoutHorizontalAlign.Center;
    });

    groupItemLayer2.Items.Add(m => Model.DepartmentId, item =>
    {
        item.Caption = Resources.Resource.Department;
        item.CaptionStyle.Font.Bold = true;

        item.NestedExtension().ComboBox(comboBox =>
        {
            comboBox.Name = "DepartmentId";
            comboBox.Properties.TextField = "Text";
            comboBox.Properties.ValueField = "Value";
            comboBox.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
            comboBox.Properties.DataSource = ViewData["Departments"];
            comboBox.ShowModelErrors = true;

            comboBox.PreRender = (s, e) =>
            {
                MVCxComboBox cb = (MVCxComboBox)s;
                if (!(cb.SelectedIndex > 0) || cb.Value.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            };
        });
    });

    var groupItemLayer3 = groupItem.Items.AddGroupItem(groupSettings =>
    {
        groupSettings.CellStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        groupSettings.ShowCaption = DefaultBoolean.True;
        groupSettings.Caption = Resources.Resource.Required;
        groupSettings.GroupBoxDecoration = GroupBoxDecoration.Default;
        groupSettings.ColumnCount = 1;
        groupSettings.SettingsItems.HorizontalAlign = FormLayoutHorizontalAlign.Left;
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.RecruitingFormsRows.Count - 1; i++) //for some reason it runs once at the end of full file generation and it triggers index out of collection error
    {
        var groupItemLayer4 = groupItemLayer3.Items.AddGroupItem(groupSettings =>
        {
            groupSettings.CellStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            groupSettings.ShowCaption = DefaultBoolean.True;
            groupSettings.Caption = Resources.Resource.EmployeesOnFunction + " " + (i+1);
            groupSettings.GroupBoxDecoration = GroupBoxDecoration.Default;
            groupSettings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            groupSettings.ColumnCount = 2;
            groupSettings.SettingsItems.HorizontalAlign = FormLayoutHorizontalAlign.Left;
        });

        groupItemLayer4.Items.Add(m => Model.RecruitingFormsRows.ToList()[i].CategoryId, item =>
        {
            item.Caption = Resources.Resource.Category;
            item.CaptionStyle.Font.Bold = true;

            item.NestedExtension().ComboBox(comboBox =>
            {
                comboBox.Properties.TextField = "Text";
                comboBox.Properties.ValueField = "Value";
                comboBox.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
                comboBox.Properties.DataSource = @ViewData["Categories"];
                comboBox.ShowModelErrors = true;
                comboBox.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

                comboBox.PreRender = (s, e) =>
                {
                    MVCxComboBox cb = (MVCxComboBox)s;
                    if (!(cb.SelectedIndex > 0) || cb.Value.ToString() == "0")
                    {
                        cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                };
            });
        });

        groupItemLayer4.Items.Add(m => Model.RecruitingFormsRows.ToList()[i].NumberOfPersons, item =>
        {
            item.Caption = Resources.Resource.NumberOfPersons;
            item.CaptionStyle.Font.Bold = true;

            item.NestedExtension().TextBox(textBox =>
            {
                textBox.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                textBox.ShowModelErrors = true;
            });
        });
    }

    groupItemLayer3.Items.Add(item =>
    {
        item.Width = Unit.Pixel(160);
        item.Caption = "";
        item.HorizontalAlign = FormLayoutHorizontalAlign.Center;
        item.NestedExtension().Button(s =>
        {
            s.Name = "SubmitFormButton";
            s.Text = Resources.Resource.Send;
            s.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
            s.Width = Unit.Pixel(150);
        });
    });

}).GetHtml()
```

I receive the post in a controller like this because I could not figure out why it was not binding the rows to the main model.

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true)]
public ActionResult AddRecruitingForm(RecruitingForm item, List<RecruitingFormsRow> itemRows)
{
    DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
    bool hasRowErrors = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < itemRows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (itemRows[i].CategoryId > 0 && itemRows[i].NumberOfPersons > 0)
        {
            itemRows[i].Inserted_At = dateTimeNow;
            itemRows[i].Updated_At = dateTimeNow;

            item.RecruitingFormsRows.Add(itemRows[i]);
        }
        else if (itemRows[i].CategoryId > 0 && itemRows[i].NumberOfPersons == 0)
        {
            if (itemRows[i].NumberOfPersons == 0)
            {
                ViewData["EditRowError" + itemRows[i].Id] = Resources.Resource.NumberOfPersonsCantBe0;
            }
            item.RecruitingFormsRows.Add(itemRows[i]);
            hasRowErrors = true;
        }
    }

    if(hasRowErrors)
    {
        item.RecruitingFormsRows.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < itemRows.Count; i++)
        {
            item.RecruitingFormsRows.Add(itemRows[i]); 
            //reload all the items received back into the whole model
        }

        RecruitingFormsRow modelRow = new RecruitingFormsRow();
        item.RecruitingFormsRows.Add(modelRow);

        LoadViewData(); //Loads the date for the combo boxes in ViewData
        return View("AddRecruitingForm", item);
    }
}
```

My main issue is that if I have to return an error message (ex I have category chosen but the number of people is 0 then I should send the model back as a response with an error message attached) the fields into the list are set back to initial values (0's and nulls).

I checked the variables using the debugger and the values do get to the view in the main object (ex: I set CategoryId to 5 using debugger in the get function before I sent the model to the view and could see it using the expression bellow so the values do get to the view as expected but they won't get set to the objects themselves.

```
var test = Model.RecruitingFormsRows.ToList()[i].CategoryId;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I tried with a foreach loop instead of a for loop which loaded the view correctly but later on I found out that it is impossible to post the values because the fields get the same name by doing that.

Comment: I have also tried setting the comboBox's name like this: ```comboBox.Name = "RecruitingForm.RecruitingFormsRows[" + i + "].CategoryId";``` to no avail, it doesn't help

Comment: Why is your action bound to `RecruitingForm item, List<RecruitingFormsRow> itemRows`? Isn’t `List<RecruitingFormsRow>` already _part of_ `RecruitingForm`? And thus, shouldn’t your `RecruitingFormsRow`s be bound to `item. RecruitingFormsRows`?

Comment: It should but for some reason it doesn't. The item.RecruitingFormsRows comes empty and the information comes into the secondary declared List<RecruitingFormsRow> itemRows. I'm not sure why it happens like that but I found out by try and fail that by declaring the second variable it comes in there.